# How to detect if your app was "side-loaded" with a different certificate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate

Is there a way to detect if your app was sideloaded with a different (free) dev certificate on iOS via code?

Answer (score 2):

An app can check the certificate it was signed with, the certificate details should be enough for you to determine it was load-loaded. E.g. if you normally sign your apps with a particular certificate and that isn't the one app finds then you have been side-loaded.

The code to do the checking is not long but you do need to understand what you are doing and write the appropriate custom checks for your app. Try starting with Apple's [Code Signing Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929).

HTH